# Is there a publicly available CSS file for highlighting code snippets?

Tags: css, frontend, syntax-highlighting

On the site https://jgthms.com/web-design-in-4-minutes/ (built from https://github.com/jgthms/web-design-in-4-minutes) the highlighting of code snippets is done via span elements that are given a color in CSS:

```
.keyword {
  color: #ab7967;
}

.unit {
  color: #fac863;
}

.attribute {
  color: #5fb3b3;
}

.number {
  color: #f99157;
}
```

Is there a CSS file publicly available that would allow code highlighting like this for the common programming languages (Python, C++, Javascript)?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of any IDE and the themes associated with it to get the syntax highlighting, even most IDE's allow you to customise the same also.

Try [VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) or [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/download)